# python urllib2 post data

Tags: python, linux, urllib2, urllib

I need to pass some data to the following urllib2 request,

```
    handler = urllib2.HTTPSHandler()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    request.add_header("Accept",'application/*+xml;version=5.5')
    request.add_header("x-vcloud-authorization",authtoken)
    request.get_method = lambda: method
    data = "some XML request"
    try:
        connection = opener.open(request)
    except urllib2.HTTPError,e:
        connection = e

    if connection.code == 200:
        data = connection.read()
        #print "Data from Entity"
        #print "Data :", data
    else:
        print "ERROR", connection.code
        sys.exit(1)
```

will

```
connection = opener.open(request, data)
```

work? if not how can I pass data to the request?

**UPDATE:**

I think i can pass it this way

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, data="some data")
```

Comment: use this lib requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ is the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method urllib2.Request.add_data:

```
request.add_header('xxxx', 'vvvv')
request.add_data('some XML request')
opener.open(request)
```

This converts it to a POST request.

Comment: Yes. Any string you put in there will be received by the server as the request body.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2
import json

# Whatever structure you need to send goes here:
jdata = json.dumps({"username":"...", "password":"..."})
urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/", jdata)
```

But i recommend to you use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is the best option to handle http calls.

Comment: Yeap, absolutely. Is the best option to handle http requets.